# Is there an extension of android studio which generates my flutter app's widget map?

Tags: flutter, android-studio

Is there an extension of the android studio which generates my flutter app's widget map?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the plugin is called Flutter inspector and the map is called the Flutter widget tree. You can read about it in the [docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/devtools/inspector).